# Parse.com Query only returning first 100

Tags: c#, parse-platform, xamarin

Hi I was wondering why my parse query was only returning an 100 objects when their is over 3000 rows in the parse db. I am using this in a xamrian.ios application and its only getting the first 99 objects back any ideas help is appreciated. And yes I did debug the code its only retreieving the first 99 objects back.

```
public async void populateFromParseLocalDB()
    {
        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("clinics");;
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();


        int i;
        foreach (var record in results)
        {
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine("in for each");
            var name = record.Get<String>("Name");
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }

        int mycount = i;
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug your code first line by line?

Comment: Yes as soon as its the results is only 99 records in it but the db has 3000 rows

Comment: Make sure you don't have any TOP(X) statement in sp

Comment: @malkam this is not a stored proc your answer is illrelavant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Parse Docs](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#queries-constraints):

> You can limit the number of results by calling Limit. By default,
>   results are limited to 100, but anything from 1 to 1000 is a valid
>   limit:

Comment: this is for a postcode search using lat and long so I want all records aviable to me how do i get them all back and push into local class

Comment: Read the docs.  Combine the Limit and Skip parameters and make multiple calls to get all the data you need.